# ChartJS Line Chart shoud not start at 0 with all Lines

Tags: javascript, json, chart.js

I have a linechart, with different lines. These lines have different x positions and have to start at its position. But all starts at 0.
 If i use scatter, the positions are all right.
 How can i configure the line chart to start at its x position? Or how can i draw a line in the scatter chart?

configure:

```
new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'line',
    data: JSON.parse(data),
    options: {
        scales: {
            yAxes: [{
                stacked: false,
                ticks: {
                    beginAtZero: false
                }
            }]
        },
        spanGaps: false,
        showLine: true,
        fill: true
    }
});
```

example data:

```
{
   "labels": ["5 hours"],
   "datasets": [{
    "data": [{
       "y": 36997,
       "x": 0
     }],
  "label": "1657818086198724510",
  "backgroundColor": "rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.8)",
  "borderColor": "rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.8)",
  "fill": false
},
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

found my error,

it was the showLine

shoud be showLines :-(